Jetpack Compose with just one button uses too much CPU
I'm new to Jetpack Compose, and I was trying it.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm making one for desktop.
I created a new Jetpack Compose with IntelliJ IDEA, and I runned it nothing changed with IntelliJ IDEA.
This is my whole code created by IntelliJ IDEA:
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, World!") }

    MaterialTheme {
        Button(onClick = {
            text = "Hello, Desktop!"
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}

It made a window with a purple button:
My Jetpack Compose window (screenshot)
But its CPU usage is around 10-15% in task manager although I didn't do anything.
I did nothing - but it uses too much cpu (screenshot)
If I move my mouse pointer over it, the CPU usage increases up to 33-35%
When moving mouse pointer over it (screenshot)
This is too high compared to other applications.
While watching a 4k video in YouTube uses CPU around 30% when it first loads, and then never more than 15% after it stabilized, Jetpack Compose uses 12-18% steadily.
However, I don't know if it's an error in the task manager because in the resource monitor, however much I moved the mouse, the CPU usage never increased over 10.
What I tried:

I tried making it into an .exe file, but the cpu usage was similar.

I googled about it many times, but I couldn't find any information about it.


Is it normal to use that much cpu for just displaying one button?
Or it is reloading the button again and again because of my mistake?
Thank you so much for your help.
